# Local web server configuration for PhpStorm

Tags: php, configuration, localhost, phpstorm

I'm new to PhpStorm. In the previous IDE that I used to code in, I had the ability to specify/configure the php engine and web server root directory in my development machine only one time and run any piece of php belonging to whatever project in it without any further configuration. In PhpStorm, it seems that every project requires its own server configuration.

Any help to specify a OneForAll configuration that could let me focus on my code ;-) ?

**My System:**

- XAMMP on top of Windows XP.
- PhpStorm v. 1.0.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I GOT AN ANSWER FROM THE PHPSTORM TEAM**.

Unfortunately, a one-time-configuration does just not exist in the current release (v. 1.0.2). Every project needs to have its own PHP environment configuration.

A feature request is issued for the 2.1 release, let's wait and see.